# Retrieving username and password from SQLite in Shiny R

Tags: r, sqlite, shiny

I am developing a `shiny` Application. So far I could make the following scripts, But I intend to retrieve the username and password from `SQLite` which I could not figure it out. I mean, I need to have my username and password on a table in `SQLite`, and then check if the inserted username and password are matched.

Any help would be great.

Appreciate!

**server.R**

```
server = (function(input, output,session) {

  USER <- reactiveValues(Logged = Logged)

  observe({ 
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      if (!is.null(input$Login)) {
        if (input$Login > 0) {
          Username <- isolate(input$userName)
          Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
          Id.username <- which(my_username == Username)
          Id.password <- which(my_password == Password)
          if (length(Id.username) > 0 & length(Id.password) > 0) {
            if (Id.username == Id.password) {
              USER$Logged <- TRUE
            } 
          }
        } 
      }
    }    
  })
  observe({
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {

      output$page <- renderUI({
        div(class="outer",do.call(bootstrapPage,c("",ui1())))
      })
    }
    if (USER$Logged == TRUE) 
    {
      output$page <- renderUI({
        div(class="outer",do.call(navbarPage,c(inverse=TRUE,title = "Contratulations you got in!",ui2())))
      })
      print(ui)
    }
  })
})
```

**ui.R**

```
ui = (htmlOutput("page"))
```

**ui1.R**

```
    Logged = FALSE;
    my_username <- "ester"
    my_password <- "silva"
    ui1 <- function(){
          tagList(
            div(id = "login",
                wellPanel(textInput("userName", "Username"),
                          passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
                          br(),actionButton("Login", "Log in"))),
            tags$style(type="text/css", "#login {font-size:10px;   text-align: left;position:absolute;top: 40%;left: 50%;margin-top: -100px;margin-left: -150px;}")
 )}
```

**ui2.R**

```
ui2 <- function(){tagList(tabPanel("Test"))}
```

Comment: Where is your SQLite code? Did you make an attempt with RSQLite or DBI? What does this code currently do?

Comment: @Parfait, This code is a login with ester as username and silva as the password. Since it is my first time that I am doing an application, I have no idea from which point I have to start. I also read a few related posts but they made me more confused.

Comment: Really? [RSQLite](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-and-sqlite-part-1/) is much easier than Shiny! Simply connect to your db and query your users table by the Shiny ui entered username and password: `df <- dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE username = 'ester' AND password = 'silva'")`. If `nrow(df) > 1`, user exists.

Comment: @Parfait, I give it a try. Anyway, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **Initial setup**

Initialy, you need to create database - file `db.sqlite` where all tables (users data) are stored. File should be in the same folder as `ui.R` and `server.R` - if not, change path in `dbname="relative_path/db.sqlite"` argument.

```
library(RSQLite)
# creates connection to SQLite db, if not exists - creates one
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname="db.sqlite")

# create table users where logins and passwords are stored
dbSendQuery(conn = db,
        "CREATE TABLE users
        (username TEXT,
        password TEXT)")

# insert some initial data to work with
dbSendQuery(db, "INSERT INTO users ( username, password)
                 VALUES ( 'ester', 'silva' );")
```

---

### **Code modification**

Instead of your lines.

```
Id.username <- which(my_username == Username)
Id.password <- which(my_password == Password)
if (length(Id.username) > 0 & length(Id.password) > 0) {
  if (Id.username == Id.password) {
    USER$Logged <- TRUE
   } 
 }
```

Put this, to switch from R to SQLite functionality. Result of a query is an `rowid` of user, which can be treated as `uid` and passed further to obtain user data.

```
      query <- sprintf({"
        SELECT rowid 
        FROM users 
        WHERE username='%s' and password ='%s'"}, 
        Username, Password, serialize=F) 
      db   <- RSQLite::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="db.sqlite")
      user <- RSQLite::dbGetQuery(db, query) 
      RSQLite::dbDisconnect(db)
      if ( length(user$rowid)==1 ) {
        USER$Logged <- TRUE
      }
```

---

### **Working example**

```
library(shiny)
Logged = FALSE;
my_username <- "ester"
my_password <- "silva"
ui2 <- function(){tagList(tabPanel("Test"))}

ui1 <- function(){
  tagList(
    div(id = "login",
        wellPanel(textInput("userName", "Username"),
                  passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
                  br(),actionButton("Login", "Log in"))),
    tags$style(type="text/css", "#login {font-size:10px;   text-align: left;position:absolute;top: 40%;left: 50%;margin-top: -100px;margin-left: -150px;}")
  )}

server = (function(input, output,session) {

  USER <- reactiveValues(Logged = Logged)

  observe({ 
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      if (!is.null(input$Login)) {
        if (input$Login > 0) {
          Username <- isolate(input$userName)
          Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
          query <- sprintf({"
            SELECT rowid 
            FROM users 
            WHERE username='%s' and password ='%s'"}, 
                           Username, Password, serialize=F) 
          db   <- RSQLite::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="db.sqlite")
          user <- RSQLite::dbGetQuery(db, query) 
          RSQLite::dbDisconnect(db)
          if ( length(user$rowid)==1 ) {
            USER$Logged <- TRUE
          }
        } 
      }
    }    
  })
  observe({
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {

      output$page <- renderUI({
        div(class="outer",do.call(bootstrapPage,c("",ui1())))
      })
    }
    if (USER$Logged == TRUE) 
    {
      output$page <- renderUI({
        div(class="outer",do.call(navbarPage,c(inverse=TRUE,title = "Contratulations you got in!",ui2())))
      })
      print(ui)
    }
  })
})
ui = (htmlOutput("page"))


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```